# Нужна помощь в составлении регулярного выражения js

Tags: javascript

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, которое разрешает ввод только латинских буквы, и знаки _ - .

Answer (score 2):

Выражение будет такое: `[a-zA-Z-_\.]`

Answer (score 1):

`/^[a-z_\-.]*$/i`

---

`^`, `$` - начало и конец строки, соотв.
`[]` - символьный класс (совпадение с любым символом из перечисленных)
`*` - любое количество (включая 0) повторов предыдущего элемента
`a-z` - диапазон, включающий все латинские буквы
`\-` - экранирование символа `-`, т.к. в классе он означает диапазон, а нам нужен сам символ буквально
`_`, `.` - сами эти символы буквально (в классе, точка экранирования не требует)
Флаг `i` - отключает чувствительность к регистру символов входной строки

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Помогло

Comment: @daemko, изначально я написал неправильное выражение по невнимательности к вопросу, сейчас ответ исправлен.